# Geometric interpretation of Supersymmetry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, superalgebra

Is there a geometric interpretation of supersymmetry? I.e., if one has a manifold $\mathcal {M} $, and there are $\mathcal {N} $ SUSY generators,  then is there a geometric interpretation of the SUSY generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are tied to groups, and groups are tied to with geometry, one would expect so. From the wiki article on supersymmetry:

> Supersymmetry can be reinterpreted in the language of noncommutative geometry and quantum groups. In particular, it involves a mild form of noncommutativity, namely supercommutativity. See the [main article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry_as_a_quantum_group) for more details.

Comment: Link is broken.